# Docker, nginx Зачем нужна деректива resolver в моем случае?

Tags: nginx, docker

Есть следующая настройка в nginx.conf:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=15s;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
    alias /var/www/phpmyadmin/;
    index index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri = 404;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^\/phpmyadmin\/(.+\.php)(.*)$; # index.php
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name; 
      fastcgi_pass phpmyadmin:9000;
    }
  }

}
```

Я пытаюсь понять, для чего здесь понадобилась resolver 127.0.0.11 и почему именно такой адрес? Этот пример я нашел в интернете, без этой директивы у меня phpmyadmin не работает.

Comment: Чтобы прописанный в `fastcgi_pass` домен `phpmyadmin` можно было преобразовать в IP-адрес. Без указания корректного DNS-сервера отрезолвить этот домен не получится и подключиться к адресу phpmyadmin тоже не получится

Comment: Низачем. Уберите. Статичные хосты резолвятся при запуске

Comment: @Alexey Ten, не работает ничего без него, 502 ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб найти домен `phpmyadmin`, адрес которому выдает докер. Докер отвечает на DNS запросы отдельно от системного ресолвера.

docker запускает dnsmasq на этом адресе чтоб настроить сеть и днс на контейнерах.

Comment: То есть phpmyadmin:9000 превращается в 127.0.0.11:9000?

Comment: И мне все равно не понятно, как оно по этому айпишнику находит этот домен и почему именно по нему, а не например по 127.0.0.99 (Хотя видимо там можно абсолютно любой указать)

Comment: нет, там скорее всего "172.17.0.1" или чтото в этом роде.

Comment: Но какой мне указать? Я пробовал 127.0.0.1 и 127.0.0.11 разницы никакой

Comment: Попробуй указать хост докера

Comment: Дак у меня работает с любым) Я пытаюсь понять, какой лучше? И почему?